# Windows Server 2003 terminal server extreme logon times

Tags: windows-server-2003, performance, login

For the past week my users have been experiencing extreme logon times. They are generally in the 20 minute range or more. I will lay out my research below to see if anyone may know how to find the root cause.

Terminal Server:

- x2 Quad core Xeon 2.6Ghz processors
- 16 GB ram
- x2 300GB SAS drives in Raid1
- Gigabit Lan
- Windows 2k3 Enterprise
- Average users connected 23

Domain Controler:

- Windows 2k3 Enterprise
- Gigabit lan
- Also stores roaming profiles

Most of the information I have gathered has been from parsing the USEREVN.log file. I wrote a custom parsing tool to try and glean as much information as possible from logging the users login processes. Here are some stats from those logs.

- The single most logged routine is ReconcileFile
- The most time spent total is on the routine ReconcileFile
- There is no single routine that is taking an extreme amount of time.
- ReconcileFile and RecurseDirectory take 7 times longer than GPO processing
- The average time spent per ReconcileFile routine is 223 milliseconds with normal user load
- the average time spent per ReconcileFile routine is 220 milliseconds when only 1 user is accessing the system
- From a user prospective the average execution time of a thread handling a routine for that particular user can be upwards of 1 second, though, the average time per routine still may be about 223 milliseconds.
- A particular user may have routines being executed to log them on over a 20 minute period but actually only have around 2 minutes of execution time devoted to their login.

Having gathered all that diagnostic data I still can't find the root cause of the issue. The servers resources have not changed between this week and last. So, I'm at a loss of were to look next.

Comment: I'm impressed by your work gathering data. I find the `USERENV.LOG` to be frustratingly verbose but low on detail. If I were you, I'd also run a Process Monitor trace on a user logging-on to see how that looks, too. I suspect that's going to help you pinpoint the root cause.

Comment: I agree on that log. Its a real mess. And it gets way worse in a multi-user environment like a terminal server. The worst part of all of it though is I don't have a control to compare too. I don't know what the routine times were like a week ago.

Comment: 1) If you haven't changed the servers, what else might have changed? Is there AntiVirus with auto-update on either server? Would they have installed Windows Updates? Has someone plugged something in which is saturating or otherwise breaking the network (e.g. a cable loop)? 2) Divide-and-conquer troubleshooting: If you create a fresh user account, is that slow to logon? Can you make a user exempt from roaming profiles so they only logon locally and compare?

Comment: Are you redirecting My Documents or any other folders?

Comment: Possible changes: AV pattern update. Windows updates on the 19th, network throughput seems low but stable at about .21 Gbps. None of the Win updates seem like an obvious culprit but are still going to be a top target.

Comment: As for redirection, some have redirected desktops and my documents. I could probably give some relief on file copies by redirecting AppData as well but that's more treating the symptom than the problem.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler on the idea of testing local logins, I'm not sure how worthy it is but the Admin account does not have a roaming profile and logs in as fast as one would expect. The userenv.log also points to roaming profile file reconciliation as the issue. The difficulty is not knowing what the normal file reconciliation process time should look like.

Comment: Can you make an account have a roaming profile as empty and new as possible and compare that with the admin account? Re the network running at 20% speed, can you check if the network interfaces on both servers and both switchports are showing connected at 1000Mb / full duplex?

Comment: So this morning I did my routine logging and am floored. The avg time of the ReconcileFile routine is down to 43ms. I did not do anything to the server. The only change to the entire network was we swapped out a core switch that doesn't even interconnect the terminal server to the domain controller / profile storage location. Sigh...

Comment: After a few more days of testing I still don't have any more answers as to what happened. After we swapped out that switch (which wasn't swapped due to any failure) my users are back to normal login times. Today I recorded a 23ms average time on the ReconcileFile routine. I'm really not sure what to make of it. I guess the lesson here is throw a dart at the network dartboard if you have excessive login times?

Comment: The mystery continues today. My server as all of a sudden decided to jump back up to the 227 ms timing for the ReconcileFile routine. I'm going to reboot the network tonight to see how it affects the issue. On the up side at least I will get to test my theory from the previous time this occurred.

Comment: We are still continuing to deal with this issue. I'm posting this comment as I've gone through the pain of testing each non-Microsoft service that is running on the affected server. I've been able figure out that it is specifically the Trend Micro Server Protect Antivirus service that is responsible here. There is no resolution as of yet. Trend is now involved. I'll post the exact fix once they have it figured out.